# Visual Studio Team Services online - "free for 5 users" clarification

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

We are using Visual Studio Team Services (online) to manage our source code and backlog. We have 2 users who have Visual Studio Enterprise Subscriptions. I understand that VSTS is free for up to 5 users. My question is: would the 2 licenced users be included in the 5, or would we be able to have up to 5 additional users (making a total of 7)?
I'm sure I read somewhere before that the users with Visual Studio licences wouldn't be included in the 5 but can't find any clarification online now.

Would be interested to hear if anyone has first hand experience of this one way or the other. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because licensing questions are explicitly off topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is free for up to 5 unlicensed users. Licensed users do not count against your 5 free users.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and apologies for the off topic question